# Converting matlab code to python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Okay so I have a datafile from an EEG scan (a binary file, data.eeg), and in matlab the code to read the file and plot a section of the data goes like this:

```
sr=400;                                                     % Sample Rate
Nyq_freq=sr/2;                                              % Nyquist Frequency
fneeg=input('Filename  (with path and extension) :', 's');  
t=input('How many seconds in total of EEG ? : ');
ch=input('How many channels of EEG ? : ');
le=t*sr;                                                    % Length of the Recording
fid=fopen(fneeg, 'r', 'l');                                 % Open the file to read 
EEG=fread(fid,[ch,le],'int16');                             % Read Data -> EEG Matrix
fclose ('all');     
plot(EEG(:,3))
```

Here is my attempt to "translate"

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pylab import *

sample_rate = 400
Nyquist = sample_rate/2.
fneeg = raw_input("Filename (full path & extension): ")
t = int(raw_input("How many secs in total of EEG?: "))
ch = int(raw_input("How many channels of EEG?: "))
le = t*sample_rate
fid = open(fneeg, 'r')
EEG = fromfile(fneeg, int16)
```

Here's where things get confusing to me. According to the documentation, matlab's fread is a method of reading binary files via fread(loaded_file, size, data_type). The alternative in python is using numpy's fromfile and reshaping (according to this thread here: [MATLAB to Python fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752333/matlab-to-python-fread)) using the built in reshape function. I'm not sure how this works, or even relates to the matlab method? I'm sorry if my question is confusing, matlab is still very new to me

Edit: If you wanna look have a look at the file here it is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzm6uvjfm9gpamk/data.eeg

Edit2: The answers to the raw inputs are t=10, ch=32. In fact I'm not sure why I'm even asking for user input now that I think about it..

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input file ?

Comment: It sounds like you've already answered your own question. As near as I can tell, you just want `eeg = numpy.fromfile(filename, 'int16').reshape(ch, le)`.  Also, you can skip explicitly opening the file, if you'd like. `fromfile` will accept a filename as well as a file object.

Comment: I've added a link to the data in the edit. @JoeKington, that was my reasoning too, but why is it that we need to reshape? I don't understand the reasoning, you know what I mean?

Comment: @Norman, `np.fromfile` just returns a 1d array (of length `ch*le`, but you want it to be a `ch` X `le` matrix.  `reshape` simply makes this change, without touching the data itself.

Comment: @NormanB, do you happen to be using Neuroscan? I'm trying to import Neuroscan files (.cnt or .eeg) to python and running into a lot of issues.

Comment: @Amyunimus What are the issues?

Comment: @NormanB The MNE EEG analysis package does not read them and there is no way to convert .CNT files to .FIF using python.

Comment: You could check out mne-python: http://martinos.org/mne/stable/getting_started.html

Comment: If that doesn't work out for you, it shouldn't be too hard to write a script to read the files from the .vhdr files. I may have already written something of the sort but I can't remember

Comment: @NormanB Yup, that was what I was using. I'm not familiar with the .vhdr files, just .cnt and .fif. If you have a helper script, I'd love to take a look at it. You can find my email on my webpage, from my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments by yourself and @JoeKington, this should work (I removed the input stuff for testing)

```
import numpy as np

sample_rate = 400
Nyquist = sample_rate/2.0
fneeg = 'data.eeg'
t = 10 
ch = 32
le = t*sample_rate
EEG = np.fromfile(fneeg, 'int16').reshape(ch, le, order='F')
```

Without the reshape, you get:

```
In [45]: EEG
Out[45]: array([ -39,  -25,  -22, ..., -168, -586,  -46], dtype=int16)

In [46]: EEG.shape
Out[46]: (128000,)
```

With reshaping:

```
In [47]: EEG.reshape(ch, le, order='F')
Out[47]: 
array([[ -39,  -37,  -12, ...,    5,   19,   21],
       [ -25,  -20,    7, ...,   20,   36,   36],
       [ -22,  -20,    0, ...,   18,   34,   36],
       ..., 
       [ 104,  164,   44, ...,   60,  -67, -168],
       [ 531,  582,   88, ...,   29, -420, -586],
       [ -60,  -63,  -92, ...,  -17,  -44,  -46]], dtype=int16)

In [48]: EEG.reshape(ch, le, order='F').shape
Out[48]: (32, 4000)
```

Comment: Haha, you're welcome, but the credit is due to you and @Joe :P

Comment: NormanB - Just on a side note, it's possible (? I can't remember.) that matlab uses column-major ordering instead of row major... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order  In that case, the results were probably written to disk in column-major order, and you'd do `fromfile(...).reshape(le, ch).T` (note that `le` and `ch` are swapped).  Just something to be aware of, at any rate. If your data looks garbled, give it a try.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right it does(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). Good catch!

Comment: By the way @askewchan how did you get your code to look like it was written in ipython notebook?? That's pretty neat

Comment: That's actually copied and pasted from ipython (not notebook).  A nice compromise between ipython notebook and the standard python interpreter.

Comment: Nice catch, @Joe!  An easier fix is to use `order='F'`.  I've edited to reflect it.

Comment: @askewchan - Good point on the `order='F'`! I always forget, and wind up having lots of rather unreadable `reshape(...).T`'s around.